# GnomeMplayer accents displayed as "?", how i fix it?

Tags: subtitle, gmplayer

For some reason in GnomeMplayer the accents in the subtitles are displayed as '?', Is there a way to fix this problem?

What I've tried: edit, preferences, language settings, I put everything into Brazilian Portuguese and UTF-8 ... and I tried also the ISO 8859-1 encoding. but after restarting the screen returns to ISO 8859-15.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and my system language is brazilian portuguese.

Thanks e sorry for my bad english

Comment: Solved. I edit the "config" file in .mplayer folder in my home. I only put this: subcp = iso8859-1  , and al ok now. Thanks for all.

Comment: You should put that as an answer and accept your own answer. That way, this will show up as a solved question. This is perfectly acceptable practice.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

I only  edit the "config" file in .mplayer folder in my home. I only put this: subcp = iso8859-1 , and al ok now. Thanks for all.